# How to read JPEG2000 of Sentinel-2 data in R

Tags: r, rgdal, jpeg2000

I am trying to use the [`rgdal`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rgdal) package to open multiple Sentinel-2 data of JPEG2000 format.

The issue I am running into is:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
d:/data/T35SMD_20161227T091402_B01.jp2' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

Although, I have updated my installation of the `rgdal` package and use updated gdal binaries that support JPEG2000, which had support [introduced in v1.9.0](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jpeg2000.html).

```
rgdal: version: 1.2-5, (SVN revision 648)
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15
```

When I perform `gdalDrivers()` command, the entry for `JPG2000` is not listed there among other drivers.

Can anyone please tell me how could I solve this problem? I have plenty of S-2 data and converting them to tiff in QGIS or any similar program is no option for me.

I have also found few similar questions on this theme (c.f. [open jpeg2000 sentinel 2 in r](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211157/open-jpeg2000-sentinel-2-in-r)), however it seems there is no straight answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command-line utility gdal_translate, as documented here: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_sentinel2.html. You will have a lot more flexibility, and likely better speed and memory handling. Example that is given there is:

```
gdal_translate SENTINEL2_L1C:S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20150818T101440_R022_V20150813T102406_20150813T102406.xml:10m:EPSG_32632 10m.tif -co TILED=YES --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1000 --config GDAL_NUM_THREADS 2
```

There's not really a solid argument for doing that much heavy lifting in R, especially through something that is essentially a wrapper.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion, I have included the gdal_translate() from gdalUtils into my code and it works fine.