# Downscaling sentinel-2 bands to 10m using R language

Tags: r, raster, satellite-image, sentinel2, sentinelsat

I'm trying to calculate [NDRE](https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/si-single.php?sensor_id=96&rsindex_id=223) using [sentinel-2 bands](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-sentinel-2?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects) in R language.

The formula for **NDRE** = (nir-re)/(nir+re)
**nir**- Near InfraRed (Band8) 
**re** - RedEdge (Band5)

My Code:

```
library(raster)
library(RStoolbox)
re_path <- "D:/R/T43PHS_20190223T050811_B05.jp2"
nir_band <- "D:/R/T43PHS_20190223T050811_B08.jp2"
re <- raster(re_path)
nir <- raster(nir_band)
plot((nir-re)/(nir+re), main="NDRE")
writeRaster(x = ((nir-re)/(nir+re)),
            filename="D:/R/T43PHS_20190223T050811.tif",
            format = "GTiff", # save as a CDF
            datatype='FLT4S'
)
```

But there seems to be an error due to **difference** in Bands5 and Band8 **resolution**.

> Error in compareRaster(e1, e2, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, crs = TRUE,  :
> different resolution

You can download **Band5** and **Band8** [Here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7072cc01281ed755c0b23f8d8950843820210315055736/c997bf)

I want to convert or downscale the 20m band into 10m band using R language and then calculate the indices, I tried using `resample()` in R I got the output "tiff" file but there is so much loss of information.

Thank you in advance

Comment: wouldn't the other way make more sense? getting 10m raster out of a 20m resolution seems to be a questionable endeavor. why not scale the 10m resolution to a 20m resolution? or is that too imprecise?

Comment: of course we can do that but I need accurate data, for accurate data downsizing 20m to 10m seems to be precise.

Comment: Now there is the `sen2r` package that can be used to download, convert, resample, and calculate indexes of Sentinel-2 image. it is done quite well and once you have mastered the workflow it becomes easy and intuitive. However you can use band 8 instead of band 8A. Those bands are very similar but the 8 band has a native resolution of 10 m

Answer (score 0):

You need to tranlate jp2 into the correct format.

**Band Resolutions:**

- B2:B4,B8 = 10 m
- B5:B7 = 20 m

Adapted the "*jp2_to_GTiff*" function from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211157/open-jpeg2000-sentinel-2-in-r/352425#comment701341_352425), with revision:

```
jp2_to_GTiff <- function(jp2_path) {
      sen2_GDAL <- raster(readGDAL(jp2_path))
      names(sen2_GDAL) <- as.character(regmatches(jp2_path,gregexpr("B0\\d", jp2_path)))
      return(sen2_GDAL)
    }

## Your files:

re_path <- "D:/R/T43PHS_20190223T050811_B05.jp2"
nir_band <- "D:/R/T43PHS_20190223T050811_B08.jp2"

## Call the function
re <- jp2_to_GTiff(re_path)
nir <- jp2_to_GTiff(nir_band)

## Resample from raster package, then write:
re_10mr <- resample(re, nir, method='bilinear')

writeRaster(x = ((nir-re_10mr)/(nir+re_10mr)),
            filename="D:/R/T43PHS_20190223T050811.tif",
            format = "GTiff", # save as a CDF
            datatype='FLT4S')
```

Note that the function uses a default GDAL conversion. The command line utility can be used as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637907/how-to-read-jpeg2000-of-sentinel-2-data-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

You can use area-to-point regression Kriging (ATPRK) to downscale S2 using the `atakrig` package. ATPRK consists of two steps:

1. regression
2. area-to-point Kriging on the regression's residuals

Assuming your coarse and fine bands are the red and nir, respectively, and the CRS is in meters, then:

```
#linear regression
library(raster)

#extract prediction part of a lm model as a raster
red = raster ("path/red.tif")
vals_red <- as.data.frame(values(red))
red_coords = as.data.frame(xyFromCell(red, 1:ncell(red))
combine <- as.data.frame(cbind(red_coords, vals_red))

nir = raster ("path/nir.tif")
nir <- resample(nir, red, method="bilinear")
vals_nir <- as.data.frame(values(nir))

s = stack(red, nir)

block.data <- as.data.frame(cbind(combine, vals_nir))
names(block.data)[3] <- "red"
names(block.data)[4] <- "nir"

block.data <- na.omit(block.data)

block.data = read.csv("path/block.data.csv")

model <- lm(formula = red ~ nir, data = block.data)
#predict to a raster
r1 <- predict(s, model, progress = 'text')
plot(r1)
writeRaster(r1, filename = "path/lm_pred.tif")

#extract residuals
map.resids <- as.data.frame(model$residuals)
x = as.data.frame(block.data$x)
y = as.data.frame(block.data$y)
map.resids <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data=map.resids, coords=cbind(x,y)) 
gridded(map.resids) <- TRUE
r <- raster(map.resids)
raster::crs(r) <- "EPSG:...." #your EPSG in meters
writeRaster(r, 
            filename = "path/lm_resids.tif", 
            format = "GTiff", 
            overwrite = T)

#area-to-point Kriging
library(atakrig)

block.data = read.csv("path/coords.csv")#csv with 2 columns (x,y) taken from the high resolution raster

nir = raster("path/nir.tif")
rsds = raster("path/lm_resids.tif")

#raster to points
nir.d = discretizeRaster(nir , 10, type = "value")
rsds.d = discretizeRaster(rsds, 10, type = "value")

# point-scale cross-variogram
aod.list <-list(rsds = rsds.d, nir = nir .d)
sv.ck <-deconvPointVgmForCoKriging(aod.list, 
                                   model = "Sph",
                                   rd = 0.5,
                                   maxIter = 50,
                                   nopar = F) #play with the rd and model

ataStartCluster()
pred.atpok <- atpKriging(rsds.d, 
                         block.data, 
                         sv.ck$nir.rsds, 
                         showProgress = T,
                         nopar = F)
ataStopCluster()

# convert result to raster for atp
pred.atpok.r <-rasterFromXYZ(pred.atpok[,-1])
#plot(pred.ataok.r)
raster::crs(pred.atpok.r) <- "EPSG:...." #your EPSG (in meters)
writeRaster(pred.atpok.r$pred, 
            'path/atpk.tif', overwrite = T)


pred = raster('path/lm_pred.tif')
atpk = raster('path/atpk.tif')
pred = resample(pred, atpk, method = 'bilinear')

red_atprk = pred + atprk

red_atprk[red_atprk <= 0] <- 0

writeRaster(red_atprk,
            filename = "path/red_atprk.tif")
```

**Important note**: In order ATPRK to produce good results, your bands (coarse and fine) needs to be **highly correlated**. You can check that by investigating the results of the `lm` (i.e., high `R2` and low `AIC` or `BIC`).